# unread count in meteor chat application for each room

Tags: meteor

i  am working on a chat app which have various channels/rooms, want to display the unread messages for each room/channel, iam able to display the unread messages count on the active room of all the participants but not on all the rooms. The helper function is not executed although the new messages are there in the inactive rooms, not sure where is the problem, appreciate for your pointers? thanks

```
'unReadCount':function(){

        var currentuserid=Meteor.userId();
        //updateChannelView
        console.log("channelid and userid"+this._id + "  " + currentuserid);
        var res=channelViewLog.findOne({channelId:this._id,userId:currentuserid})
        if(res){
            var varlastviewed=new Date(res.lastViwed);
            //console.log("last viewed timestamp"+varlastviewed + "  " + this._id +  " " + new Date());
            var res1=Messages.find({channel:this._id,createdAt: {$gte:varlastviewed},user:{ $ne: currentuserid}}).count();
            return res1;
        }

    }

Meteor.publish('PubChannelViewLog', function () {
    var currentuserid=this.userId;
    return channelViewLog.find({userId:currentuserid});
});
```

Comment: is `unreadCount` a method? what is it? It's not clear from your code drop here.

Comment: you may want to look into the packages 'tmeasday:publish-counts' to publish counts on any collection, and 'peerlibrary:reactive-publish' to handle nested queries reactively. Here you are nesting queries in your unReadCount function

Comment: unreadcount is a template helper function. thanks